# How to resize image before storing in AWS Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Can anyone give me help on resizing an image before storing it to my AWS S3 storage using Laravel? My issue is that my site is being ran through Heroku and larger images crash the site/application. I've tried installing image/intervention and nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a quick fix for this, or can you possibly point my in the right direction?

This is my code for storing:

```
if ($request->file('board_img')) {
    $hashname = $request->file('board_img')->hashName();

    Storage::disk('s3')->put('wod-pictures/', $request->file('board_img'), 'public');

    $wod_img = "wod-pictures/" . $hashname;
} else {
    $wod_img = $request->get('board_img');
}
```

Comment: Using Intervention to resize before putting on S3 should work just fine. What happened when you attempted to use it? Can you share the code and errors you encountered with it?

Comment: THis is the code I used for image intervention:  $image = Image::make($request->file('board_img')->resize(150, 300));   When I run it I get resize is not a method?

Comment: That's because you've messed up your parentheses. `$image = Image::make($request->file('board_img'))->resize(150, 300);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Image Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/), register `Image` facade and use `stream()` and `toString()` methods, for example:

```
$image = Image::make($file)->fit($width, $height)->stream();
Storage::disk('s3')->put('image_file_name', $image->__toString());
```

Comment: So Image intervention is installed but when I use the fit method it says method does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I think you are facing timeout issue (30 sec) while using heroku, i have tried uploading with below code and worked absolutely fine`

`$image = Image::make($image);
$resize_image = $image->resize(640,427);
$s3->put('path ', (string) $resize_image, 'public');`

Another way is to upload image and resize with AWS lambda method (Nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Install ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in your local system or server. On Heroku go in your app setting add build pack (https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-build-pack-ffmpeg-latest.git).
Then Your code run this line.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.Your file.' -vf scale=320:-1 '.$Scalefilename);

$filePath = 'images/'.$Scalefilename;
$image_data = public_path().'your folder'.$Scalefilename;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath,file_get_contents($image_data),'public');
```

If You want to used the class scaling the then follow this code.
https://github.com/pankajvashisht-ucreate/laraval_ffmpeg/blob/master/app/Services/Resize.php